# Android Webview Sometimes Resets?

Tags: android, webview

I wrote an app, its basically just a webview wrapper. But it works great.

I do a lot of multi-tasking on my phone and frequently switch between apps. Normally, doing this is not a problem. As I switch to and from my webview app, it retains the page I am on in the webview.

However, occasionally, it forgets the page I am on in the webview and loads up the starting page.

How do I stop this?

Comment: Save anywhere the last url and load it on create. May be it's also possible to restore the history in the same way

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the current page of the webview is currently on in case the system destroys your activity.

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    // Check if you have a previous state
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        val url = savedInstanceState.getString(SOME_KEY)
    }
}

override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle?) {
    outState?.let {
        it.putString(SOME_KEY, webView.getUrl())
    }
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
}
```

Comment: How do I store the current webview page url?

Comment: Edited answer to give more clarity